# Vim + AutoPairs (JiangMiao) How to get out of pairs?

Tags: vim

I'm still a newbie when it comes to Vim.  I installed my first plugin, AutoPairs, yesterday and spent a good amount of time trying to figure out to leave the the brackets/parentheses after typing inside.

i.e.  after type hello inside " "; how do I quickly move outside the quotations and semicolon?  I don't want to have to use ESCAPE then navigate outside the brackets/quotes then going back to insert mode everytime.  I tried looking at the autopairs.vim and saw something about "escape" but have no idea what it was about.  Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Type the closing value. It won't actually be inserted

Comment: Thank you!!!!  Can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 5):

### Quick jump to closed pair

```
input:
{
    something;|
}

(press } at |)

output:
{
    somethings;
}|
```

### Fly Mode

```
input:
{
    hello();|
    world();
}

(press } at |)

output:
{
    hello();
    world();
}|
```

Fly Mode is **DISABLED** by default.
add `let g:AutoPairsFlyMode = 1` .vimrc to turn it on

<sub>Note: `|` is your cursor position.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Type the closing value. It won't actually be inserted.

Comment: This works but then I'm wondering. What's the point of using this plugin if we still have to type the closing pair?